# Howto? IOS app for multiple resolutions

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, resolution

I have an app that I made for iphone 4 retina display a year ago.
I want to build it all over again from scratch and want to make it available for iphone 4 and iphone 5.

What is the best practice for it?

I can think of 3 ways to do it..

1. Create a button (Programatically) and position it with `Button.frame = CGRectMake`
2. Create a button (Programatically) and position it with:

   ```
   float scaleFactor = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];
   CGRect screen = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
   CGFloat widthInPixel = screen.size.width * scaleFactor;
   CGFloat heightInPixel = screen.size.height * scaleFactor;
   ```

   and start calculating percentage from screen bounds
3. position the buttons in the storyboard

What is the best practice to position the buttons so it will view correctly on both screens?

Comment: Have a look at NSLayoutConstraints...

Comment: Apple's Auto Layout system.  It's been out for a long time now, you should look it up.

Comment: Also iOS points (`CGRect`) are not device pixels, so 50x50 point will be the same size on retina as not retina. So you do not need to multiply by the scale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can autoResize feature in the in the interface builder or use it via code.

You can use Apple's Auto Layout system if your app support IOS 5 and above.